# why is this memoized factorial function returning wrong answer!

Tags: c, algorithm

I have memoized the factorial function in C as follows:

```
int fact(int n)
{
int temp;
int lookup_table[n];
if(lookup_table[n])
    return lookup_table[n]; 
else{
    if(n == 0 || n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        temp = n * fact(n-1);
        lookup_table[n] = temp;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

But then wehn I input `n = 5` ,it ouputs
-1! = 134514064
Can someone please explain what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int lookup_table[n]` should be marked static (actually it can't, you need a constant there, but it doesn't have to be too big as factorials grow very quickly), but its not really why you are getting a wrong answer. Instead, `lookup_table` is initialized to indeterminate junk, instead of 0's.

However, theres no reason to initialize it to zero when you make it static; that will be done automatically.

Oh, and as others have pointed out, you have an out of bounds error because you need to exchange `int lookup_table[n]` to use a constant rather than `n`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `lookup_table` array is declared locally; it is different in every invocation; nothing is being memoized.

Comment: +1, he should mark it as static. However, this isn't why its getting a wrong answer. (He also needs to use a constant instead of `n`)

Answer (score 2):

This `int lookup_table[n];` declares an array of n ints called lookup_table. since the valid index to that array is 0..n-1, lookup_table[n] is out of the array and will cause undefined behavior. I guess, you wanted to write: `int somevariable = lookup_table[n];` and use this variable for comparisons, or to remove this line at all.

In any case, make sure to check for boundaries when accessing that array.

Answer (score 2):

well, right away if (lookup_table[n]) is going one element beyond the length of lookup_table[].  In C, arrays have 0 based indexing.

Then there is the problem that you are declaring lookup table as an automatic (stack) variable in a recursive function that is supposed to be filling it in.  It needs to be declared outside the function in global / module scope.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
int lookup_table[n];
```

with

```
static int lookup_table[13];
```

This will make the same array accessible in the recursive function calls, and give you enough space to store all factorial values the range of `int` can support.

It would be a good idea to check that the input value is 12 or less, so that you don't run into undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, store fac[0] and fac[1] in the lookup table when you run the base case.